# How to convert factor to float without losing precision in R?

Tags: r

Here is what I have:

```
tmp[1,]

percentages      percentages.1      percentages.2      percentages.3      percentages.4 percentages.5      percentages.6      percentages.7      percentages.8      percentages.9
0.0329489291598023 0.0391268533772652 0.0292421746293245 0.0354200988467875 0.0284184514003295 0.035831960461285 0.0308896210873147 0.0345963756177924 0.0366556836902801 0.0403624382207578
```

I try converting this to numeric, since the class is `factor`, but I get:

```
as.numeric(as.character(tmp[1,]))
[1] 35 36 35 36 31 32 31 34 36 34
```

Where did these integers come from?

Comment: What is `as.character(a)` doing there?

Comment: I your example `a` isn't a vector of factors, `class(a)` returns `numeric`, something's missing in your example

Comment: not reproducible here either; but `as.numeric(as.factor(a))` *would* give similar results to what you're claiming ...

Comment: Yes, but I have a hard time trying to recreate my original example. Let me try again.

Comment: My original example vector is stuck to the dataset.

Comment: still unclear.  what is `str(tmp[1,])`, or `dput(tmp[1,])` ?

Comment: I for one am very curious how the row of a matrix or data frame could be a factor...

Comment: > str(tmp[1,])
'data.frame': 1 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ percentages  : Factor w/ 42 levels "0","0.000411861614497529",..: 35
 $ percentages.1: Factor w/ 40 levels "0","0.000411861614497529",..: 36
 $ percentages.2: Factor w/ 44 levels "0","0.000411861614497529",..: 35
 $ percentages.3: Factor w/ 42 levels "0","0.000411861614497529",..: 36
 $ percentages.4: Factor w/ 40 levels "0","0.000411861614497529",..: 31

Comment: As I suspected. Try `as.numeric(as.character(tmp[,1]))`. Note the fairly important difference between rows and columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that indexing by *rows* of a data frame gives surprising results.

Reconstruct your object:

```
tmp <- read.csv(text=
     "0.0329489291598023,0.0391268533772652,0.0292421746293245,0.0354200988467875,0.0284184514003295,0.035831960461285,0.0308896210873147,0.0345963756177924,0.0366556836902801,0.0403624382207578",
header=FALSE,colClasses=rep("factor",10))
```

Inspect:

```
str(tmp[1,])
## 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  10 variables:
##  $ V1 : Factor w/ 1 level "0.0329489291598023": 1
##  $ V2 : Factor w/ 1 level "0.0391268533772652": 1
## ... etc.
```

Converting via `as.character()` totally messes things up:

```
str(as.character(tmp[1,]))
##  chr [1:10] "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"
```

On the other hand, this (converting to a matrix first) works fine:

```
as.numeric(as.matrix(tmp)[1,])
##  [1] 0.03294893 0.03912685 0.02924217 0.03542010 0.02841845 0.03583196
##  [7] 0.03088962 0.03459638 0.03665568 0.04036244
```

That said, I have to admit that I **do not understand** the particular magic that makes `as.character()` applied to a data frame drop the information about factor levels and convert everything first to the underlying numerical codes, and then to character -- I don't know where precisely you would go to read about this.  (The bottom line is "don't extract rows of data frames if you can help it; convert them to matrices first if necessary.")

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to converting to matrix, you can just transpose the dataframe row to a column:

```
    as.numeric(as.character(t(tmp[1,])))
## [1] 0.03294893 0.03912685 0.02924217 0.03542010 0.02841845 0.03583196
## [7] 0.03088962 0.03459638 0.03665568 0.04036244
```

I think the integers seen by the OP

```
[1] 35 36 35 36 31 32 31 34 36 34
```

are factor levels, his data frame had multiple rows - 36 or more - and these are the levels of the first row.

ETA I see that `t()` converts a data frame to a matrix, so my solution is the same as Ben's.

Perhaps the reason `as.character()` doesn't work with a dataframe row is that the levels of the different columns may differ, so there isn't a common set of `levels()`. In these circumstances `as.matrix()` will convert to character, so it solves the problem.

Comment: using `t()` implicitly converts the data frame to a matrix in any case ... try `str(t(tmp[1,]))`